# PHP gettext() maximum translations?

Tags: php, gettext

I'm just starting to use gettext() and it seems to do what I need.

I'm try to find out if there is a practical or physical limit to the number of msgid/msgstr pairs that should be used in a po/mo ?

I plan to apply languages to two sites, one will have no more that 1000 translations, the other will have considerably more, possibly upto 10,000+ entries.

The larger site could be broken into sections, would it be be better to create one large po/mo file or create smaller ones for each section and apply the correct po/mo to the correct php script ?

Thanks

Comment: Benchmark it…? Unless you notice gettext calls slow down significantly or are otherwise experiencing performance problems, there's no inherent issue.

Comment: What do you mean with "each section"? Do you consider to introduce multiple gettext domains?

Comment: The large site could be considered to be in distinct sections, in reality all files are in one folder structure.  I'd wondered if I could create a po/mo pair for each 'section' and then apply that to the required files in each section using bindtextdomain/textdomain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no limits, but if your files will be large enough, it could cause performance issues.

Full documentation could be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/).

Comment: Thanks For the small site I don't think it will be a performance problem. Larger site will need some thought.

Comment: @Rocket you are welcome. Also do not forget, that on server-side MO files should be used, as they are binary data files and will be processed faster as PO's